# Group for Constraints in Bean Validation

Tags: java, jsf, bean-validation

```
@NotNull(message = "{email.error}")
@Valid(message = "{email.error}")
private String email;

@NotNull(message = "{password.error}")
@Size(min = 8, max = 16, message = "{password.error}")
private String password;
```

Is there anyway to group the constraints that belong to a single attribute?
So if one constraint is not passed, this will throw the error in question. If multiple constraints are not valid, this would still throw only this one error.
Let me illustrate what type I am after:

```
@List(constraints = {
    @NotNull, 
    @Valid
}, message = "{email.error}")
private String email;

@List(constraints = {
    @NotNull,
    @Size(min = 8, max = 16)
}, message = "{password.error}")
private String password;
```

Is something like this provided or what I have to create my own Validator for this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for the group respectively group sequence feature. Check the documentation for that. There are heaps of examples.

Regarding your example, @Valid on a String does not make sense. This annotation is for cascaded validation. Again check the documentation if you want to know more. Also an annotation like @List does not exist and wold not even compile.

Comment: This `@List` was merely an example of what I'm trying to accomplish, `@Valid` is indeed a fault in my example. I will look into this 'group sequence feature'. If it can help me any further, I will accept the answer. Thanks so far!